# IPC between multiple pods on same kubernetes node

Tags: kubernetes

I know that containers in a Pod can share data with each other via shared memory.　　
But, i have not found a way to use shared memory between Pods.

Is it possible by enabling HostIPC in Pod Security Policies?

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#host-namespaces

Of course, i know that this setting is not recommended for security reasons.

Comment: Did @Wytrzymały Wiktor answer help you to solve your problem?If yes,Please consider accepting and upvoting it. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use shared memory by setting `hostIPC: true` in the Pod Security Policy:

> `hostIPC` - Use the host’s ipc namespace. Optional: Default to false.

Notice that you can't link 2 isolated Pods (Pods not allocated on the same Node) IPC spaces together but any `hostIPC` Pod would be able to use shared memory with any other `hostIPC` Pod.

You can make sure that the Pods are scheduled together by using [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) or [Affinity and anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity).

Bear in ind that you also need to use a proper volume type. For example `emptydir` will not work but [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) can be used.

I know you mentioned that but I need to underline the fact that by using the `hostIPC` you  give ability to access data used by any pods that also use the host’s IPC namespace which creates a severe security risk. [Here](https://github.com/BishopFox/badPods/tree/main/manifests/hostipc) are some examples of it.

Comment: @Yuuuskeeeeeeee Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?